# What is the C# Equivalent of Matlab matrices vectorization?

Tags: c#, matlab, matrix, vector

I am using Dapper to convert my objects from the database into lambda-ready lists of objects (eg: `List<complexObject1>`) I am having trouble with some data analysis on these objects.

In Matlab, a vector can be made out of a matrix by utilizing the following code snippet:

```
x = eye(10,10)

y = x(:,1)

z = x(1,:)
```

I understand that C# is not a statistically-typed language, but is their any reasonable way (without using more than 3 `for` loops) to extract this data from a `List<List<string>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually C# is a statically typed language, and if you have `List<List<string>>` you can easilly access rows by using `foreach` loop or LINQ extensions like this:

```
                        foreach (var row in myList)
                        {
                            //do smth with row, row is a List<string>
                        }
                        //LINQ
                        var rows = myList.Select(row => row); //do smth with row
```

but if you wnat to get columns of your two-dimensional array I suggest you to look at [Math.NET](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics) library, it contains implementations of a lot of suitable math structures.For example there you can find implementation of matrix and vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Matlab but assuming your matrix is in a `List<List<string>>` x

```
var y = x.SelectMany(r => r[2]);
```

would give you a list of the items in column 3

```
var z = x[3];
```

would give you a list of the items in row 4